# Crontab giving no result

Tags: linux, cron, python

I have set up a cronjob on my server which is supposed to run every minute and store the output in the given file. I have been trying a lot and saw a lot of links but nothing seems to work. Following is the line which I wrote in `crontab -e`

`* * * * * /root/snmp_codes/snmp/.\/snmpstats.py -f file -g > logfile.log`

Can anyone please tell me what mistake I have made?

Comment: What's that `\/` doing in the middle of the command? You should probably have either `/root/snmp_codes/snmp/.snmpstats.py` or `/root/snmp_codes/snmp/snmpstats.py`

Comment: I gave `chmod 775 snmpstats.py` and while running the script normally I run it as `./snmpstats.py -f file -g`. I used `\\` as an escape sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the path so it's correct. Based on your comment it's likely to be `/root/snmp_codes/snmp/snmpstats.py`.

You can also modify the command so that it captures *stderr* as well as *stdout* like this (the `2>&1` attaches *stderr* to *stdout* so you get both written to the `logfile.log`):

```
* * * * * /root/snmp_codes/snmp/snmpstats.py -f file -g > logfile.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the meaning of `2>&1`. I am a bit new to Linux so I don't know much.

Comment: It redirects stderr to the same place that stdout is currently being sent to.

Comment: `/root/snmp_codes/snmp/.\/snmpstats.py` is equivalent to `/root/snmp_codes/snmp/snmpstats.py` — `\/` expands to `/` and `/./` collapses to `/`.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks. I wasn't sure enough that the `\\` would be ignored rather than treated as a literal in the middle of a path, and didn't have a window to try it out on there and then. Hopefully catching _stderr_ will lead the OP to their fault identification.